Package Django app without moving it to an external folder
We are working on a Django project with many applications. Our idea is to package them individually to use in other projects (like plugins).
Is there any way to package an application without moving it to an external folder (like documentation explains)?
We tried to add a setup.py file inside the app folder and run python setup.py sdist. The command creates the dist/ and .egg-info/ folders, but then when we install the tar.gz in a new Django project using pip, it seems that the package itself is not installed, but only the .egg-info folder.
Our current folder structure is:
project/
  app/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    serializers.py
    setup.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
  ...
  manage.py
  requirements.txt

